# sql query to find event views by time period

Tags: php, sql, database

i have the following query to return a list of events created by a user and the events total hits

```
SELECT view_id, user_id, event_id, date_viewed, COUNT( event_id ) AS views
FROM `tbl_event_views`
WHERE user_id =1
GROUP BY event_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

which is fine, but what i want to acheive is the number of views by days,weeks,months,years based on the date the listing was created to the current date.

could someone point me in the correct direction please?

really not sure where to start with this.

Many Thanks
Luke

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a column for date created for the views. There is a timestamp for sql but theres nothing to remember when an item was created unless you add it to the database. Add that column and put the timestamp into it, then you just see how many views fall into your date range with DateCreated IN (StartDate, EndDate) or something similar

Comment: Hi i have ammended my original query as i've cut out the extra bits that arent needed for this, I have a date_start field in my tbl_event_views which is a timestamp but what i dont understand how to do is get the correct date ranges? say my listing was published on the 3rd Jan how do i get every 7 day date range up until now? thanks!

Comment: You haven't said which flavor of sql you are using but if you are using MySQL or SQLServer at least there is a DateDiff function where you can supply the current date and the date your date_start, and then weeks as an argument to find out how many weeks its been. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx thats the documentation for SQLServer. I would probably use datediff on every view by days and push everything from day 1-7 into one array or list, then 8-14 into a second arrray or list, and so on if you wanted to find it by weeks

Comment: Hi sorry its mysql, im kind of thinking giving the user a date picker so they can pick their own range and then i can use the between function or the datecreated in function and just return the count of views for the range they select.

Comment: Datediff is supported by mysql and should still work for you, you just have to input the date your user picked and diff it against the date_starts